# 'Lexical' scoping of type parameters in C#

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I have 2 scenarios.

This fails:

```
class F<X>
{
  public X X { get; set; }
}
```

*error CS0102: The type '`F<X>`' already contains a definition for '`X`'*

This works:

```
class F<X>
{
  class G
  {
    public X X { get; set; }
  }
}
```

The only logical explanation is that in the second snippet the type parameter X is out of scope, which is not true...

Why should a type parameter affect my definitions in a type?

IMO, for consistency, either both should work or neither should work.

Any other ideas?

PS: I call it 'lexical', but it is probably not the correct term.

**Update:**

As per Henk's answer, here is a non-generic version displaying the same behavior, but perhaps easier to grok.

Fails:

```
class F
{
  class X { }
  public X X { get; set; }
}
```

Works:

```
class X { }
class F
{
  public X X { get; set; }
}
```

From what I can see, the C# compiler creates a lexical scope at type definition boundries.

It also implies that types and member names live in the same 'location' (or `namespace` in terms of LISP).

Comment: I dont see why the first shouldnt work, anyone able to reproduce the compiler error?

Comment: According to your update, it looks like Marcelo answered your question - he demonstrated the same thing.

Comment: @Kobi: No, not quite :)  I didn't downvote him either, as it is partially applicable.

Comment: not related, but can you check out my question leppie? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444708/start-a-new-project-in-xacc-ide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class G introduces a distinctive naming scope. If you omit the default rules, the 2 versions become:

```
public F<X>.X F<X>.X { get; set; }    // error
public F<X>.X F<X>.G.X { get; set; }  // OK
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to make a little sense  :)  And why:   class F
  {
    class X { }
    public X X { get; set; }
  }

also fails.

Answer (score 2):

`X` is defined as a type in the scope of `F`. It is similar to this:

```
class F
{
  public void X();

  public int X(); // Bad, trying to redefine X.

  class G
  {
    public string X(); // OK, different scope
  }
}
```

`F.X` isn't out of scope in `G`, but this doesn't stop `G` from defining a new `X`.

Comment: Sorry, your X is a member, mine is a type parameter. I can understand that.

Comment: Sorry to be obtuse, @leppie. Are you agreeing or disagreeing with me?