# start a new project in xacc.ide?

Tags: .net, project, ironscheme

I'm trying out xacc.ide because I'm interested in dabbling with IronScheme. I just can figure out how to start a new project. There's a whole menu for projects and dealing with them but there are only options to create "Blank File" and "File..."
How to I start a new project?

Thanks

Comment: "leppie" is a frequent visitor here.  Ping him by posting a comment to one of his answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on project creation in xacc.ide. Note that xacc.ide development stopped before I started working on IronScheme.

Also there is no project support for IronScheme in either xacc.ide and Visual Studio, but both provide simple syntax highlighting (and dumb intellisense in VS).

That said, you do not really need project support. The compiler picks up libraries and dependencies directly from the source files.

If you have more questions, feel free to ask on the [IronScheme discussion board](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/discussions) as I get notifications for that :)

Comment: Ah, what a shame. I really enjoyed it. I hate the huge bloated IDEs around. It was fast and had just the light features I needed. Project management would be cool though.